# How can I get Maximum value on Cacti Graph ?

Tags: cacti, rrdtool

I wonder how can I can retrieve from Command-line the max value on Cacti graph to an integer on a bash shell script.

I tried with the following command:

> rrdtool graph - \
>   --start=1380874818 \
>   --end=1380889218 \
>   DEF:a="/usr/share/cacti/site/rra/17/1971.rrd":'traffic_out':MAX \
>   CDEF:cdefa='a,8,*' \
>   PRINT:cdefa:MAX:"Last:%8.2lf %s"

But this did not work.